# Laravel find is returning an array instead of an object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my local the return is as expected an object, but in our development box it's returning an array. What configs should I check as to why it's returning an array instead of an object?

The code is `\App\Models\TheModel::find($id);`

Is this perhaps a model specific problem? Since other calls are returning objects as intended but this specific model on this specific page is having this error.

The Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class TheModel extends MyBaseModel
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $dates         = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

Comment: Can you share your model class?

Comment: added it in, it's basically a bare bone model

Comment: Can you share the controller code where you're implementing `\App\Models\TheModel::find($id);`?

Comment: Also which Laravel Version you're using?

Comment: Is your `MyBaseModel` extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`?

Comment: @AakashTushar Yes it is.

Comment: what do you get with `$model = new TheModel(); dd($model->find($id));` ?

Comment: @AakashTushar haven't tried that but will give it a try, what is the expected output for that one?

Comment: @magicianiam I am expecting some error if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your database.php file of your development box, within fetch you might be using

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
```

Just change it to

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS
```

Comment: It's using fetch_class